# flutter project creation creates irrelevant files

Tags: flutter, makefile, repository

I've created a new flutter project and I notice there is something odd about the structure of the project. For some reason, I'm getting tons of folders and files that I didn't get the last time I've created a project with `flutter create`.
[image]

Furthermore, when I checked the project on Github I've found out that most of my project isn't even dart but is `Makefile`
[image]

While in my last projects, more than 90% of the project (at least in such early stages) was written in dart.

Where did all these new extra folders come from?
Is there an easy way to "fix" my project and make it look more like my old one (structure-wise)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your image, left(previous) project was created before widows become available on statable version.

Now flutter have windows, Linux and macOS  are on statable release.

You will find this on [flutter.dev](https://docs.flutter.dev/)

> Build apps for any screen.

These files and folders are needed to build for different operating system. If you are thinking about why **`Dart is just 8.4%`**, I would say you need to write code, then it will increase.

Note: [this project](https://github.com/yeasin50/space_craft) was created before Linux and macOS become stable.

[image]

Comment: thanks! if i dont use all this new  stable releases and it just makes everything complicated and for me(multiple git ignore, heavier project and etc.) is there a safe way to delete some of this folders? 'Linux' and 'macOS' for example

Comment: I don't recommend deleting because in future we might get interest to build for others. It takes few megabytes' resource. You are getting above 10-2mbs on git upload, you need to check git ignore files. I found that I needed to add for Visual Studio. I use [toptal for git Ignore](https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/visualstudio,visualstudiocode,dart,flutter)

Comment: Just paste it on root git ignore file, you don't need to check inner git ignores.

Answer (score 1):

You have created the project with default command `flutter create` so it has created all platform folders because now these all platforms are stable. You can delete the platform folder if it's not in use for you.

Comment: thanks! is there a safe way to delete the folders that are irrelevant to me or should I just delete them?

Comment: For now, deletion will work though I will check it and let you know if any better option found.